Converting Date to epoch milliseconds
I have a Java Date (Fri Jun 28 10:00:01 GMT+01:00 2024) which I want to convert to Epoch millis to send to the backend.
I have tried the following:
typealias Dates = java.util.Date

fun Dates.toEpochMillis(timeZoneId: ZoneId): Long {
    val one = Instant.ofEpochMilli(time).toEpochMilli() // 1719565201000
    val three = secsToMillis(this.toLocalDateTime(timeZoneId).utcEpochSecs) // 1719568801000
    return one
}

fun Dates.toLocalDateTime(timeZoneId: ZoneId): LocalDateTime {
    return Instant.ofEpochMilli(time).atZone(timeZoneId).toLocalDateTime()
}

fun secsToMillis(timeInSecs: Long): Long {
    return timeInSecs * 1000
}

Which of the above is correct or do you suggest any other way of doing this?

Depends on what is the input and your expected output.

can you explain a bit @aled

input is Fri Jun 28 10:00:01 GMT+01:00 2024 when you say expected output? what do you mean please?

What is Dates?

and val one = Instant.ofEpochMilli(time).toEpochMilli() is correct way of doing it? as it gives me correct values

long inst = OffsetDateTime.parse("Fri Jun 28 10:00:01 GMT+01:00 2024", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss O uuuu")).toInstant().toEpochMilli(); perhaps

Your examples are confusing, you parse epoch, then get epoch back (?). If you mean you have an Instant, then yes, as its name suggests, toEpochMilli is there exactly for this purpose. If you have other date/time types, usually they have toInstant or similar method, then toEpochMilli.

BTW, it doesn't matter which timezone do you use. Epoch is always UTC.

@broot thank you for coming back are you referring to val one = Instant.ofEpochMilli(time).toEpochMilli() is this good enough?

I have no idea, because this code doesn't make too much sense for me. It takes number as an input and returns exactly the same number. If you mean the last part only, then yes, this is how we acquire epoch millis if we have an Instant.

What is the answer that you are expecting for that input? You are the only one that know that.

@aled: The questions states: "I want to convert to Epoch millis". That is the Epoch Time in milliseconds that is very well defined.

The OP seems to have some confusion about it.

if you "have a Java Date" (assuming java.util.Date, there are better data types nowadays), then you can use its getTime() method - from its documentation: "Returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT represented by this Date object." [Java based comment]

Also for most purposes I recommend that you don’t use milliseconds since the epoch for passing the value to the backend. Have your backend accept ISO 8601 format and have your Instant produce this. It’s what it’s toString method already does.

@g00se No parsing is called for. The questioner already has got an old-fashioned java.util.Date.

@Anonymous I wasn't sure about that. But I wanted to assert what kind of datetime value was being presented

You can use this:
fun Dates.toEpochMillis(): Long =
    toInstant().toEpochMilli()


actually just a more expensive way to call Date#getTime -- basically it does Instant.ofEpochMilli(date.getTime()).toEpochMilli() (both methods of Instant even do some calculating to convert milliseconds to/from seconds and nanoseconds)

@user85421 Not just (very slightly) more expensive. Also clearer and more self-explanatory.

tl;dr
In Java syntax:
long millisSinceEpoch = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant().toEpochMilli() ;

Details

I have a Java Date

Don't.
Both of the Date classes are terribly flawed, and were years ago supplanted by the modern java.time class. Avoid the legacy date-time classes wherever practical.
If you are handed a java.util.Date object, immediately convert to its replacement: java.time.Instant. Use the new to…/from… conversion methods added to the old classes. In this case, java.util.Date#toInstant.
Instant instant = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant() ;


to epoch milliseconds

Simply call Instant#toEpochMilli().
Beware of potential data loss, as an Instant may contain microseconds or nanoseconds.
long millisSinceEpoch = instant.toEpochMilli() ;


toLocalDateTime

Very much the wrong class for you to be using.
Never use LocalDateTime when handling a moment, a specific point on the timeline. A LocalDateTime purposely lacks the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC. So this class cannot represent a moment. A LocalDateTime is literally nothing more than a date with a time-of-day. So we have no idea if that date and time were meant to be seen using the wall-clock/calendar someone in Tokyo Japan, someone in Toulouse France, or someone in Toledo, Ohio US — three different moments several hours apart.
When your intention is to represent a specific point on the timeline, use only these classes: Instant, OffsetDateTime, or ZonedDateTime. (Or their equivalent in non-Gregorian calendars such a Buddhist calendar or an Islamic calendar.)

It's a bit unclear what you mean by "Both of the Date classes" - I only see one Date class being talked about in the question.

@KlitosKyriacou The Java libraries have two Date classes. This poor choice in naming is one of the many flaws in the legacy date-time classes. See the Javadoc. This Queston does not indicate which Date class.

BTW both¹ Date classes provide the getTime() method, which returns the milliseconds since Unix Epoch ||| ¹ java.sql.Date extends java.util.Date and consequently inherits its methods

@user85421 Yes, but teaching people to use terribly flawed legacy classes would be doing them a disservice. Better to focus on the modern replacement classes.

@Basil agreed, but myJavaUtilDate.toInstant().toEpochMilli() is just using Instant as a mere temporary instance, and still using one of the "terribly flawed legacy classes" (and IMHO not better than myJavaUtilDate.getTime(), not meaning performance here)

java.util.Date is mostly a wrapper over the epoch millis value, so the only thing we need to do is to get its wrapped value:
myDate.time

However, as others said, Date is a very old, obsolete and not well-designed utility. Ideally, you should not use it in the first place and instead, use more modern alternatives like: Instant, ZonedDateTime, etc. Closest equivalent to Date is Instant.
one result is correct, but it doesn't make too much sense - we create Instant for a given epoch only to get its epoch back. three result is incorrect. It is epoch for the UTC date 2024-06-28T10:00:01Z, not for +1 offset: 2024-06-28T10:00:01+01:00.
